# props are not showing up in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I have been working on my horror game and I modeled my trees, the problem is that the trees don't show up when I start the game. when I finished modeling I copy & pasted the tree into the game.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved it. it was just that the skin modifier was not applied